# how make an equation of a procedure?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, frequency, amplitude

Good day to everyone,
i have frequency spectrum
i selected top 10 peaks of that spectrum
i give weightage from 1 to 10 to top 10 frequencies by multiplying the corresponding amplitude by weightage
amplitude of heighest peak is multplied with weightage of 10, second heighest peak with 9 and amplitudes of other peaks according to thier position
at end summation of all the amplitudes that will give me value of weighted amplitude
now i want to make a equation of this procedure
for example
weighted amplitude =  = ∑ . 
where,
 = weighted amplitude
 = weightage of 1 to 10 multiply with amplitude according to position
 = amplitude
i asumed this equation but i am not sure about this i need an equation of described procedure kindly if you let me know any method for making equation i will be thankful to you
here i attached a plot where i mentioned the amplitude of corresponding frequency

Comment: I have added a code and  a figure. Validation would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I will be assuming that the spectrum is discrete, with frequencies $f_{k\in[[1,K]]}$, using the "one-based indexing" (easier here), and with amplitudes $S(f_k)$. Sorting the frequency axis from higher to lower amplitudes will result in a bijection or permutation $\sigma$ on the first $K$ integers $\sigma: [[1,K]]\mapsto [[1,K]]$.

The first ten peaks in amplitude  ($P=10$) are thus indexed by $\sigma(1),\ldots,\sigma(P)$, such that:
$$S(f_{\sigma(1)})\ge S(f_{\sigma(2)}) \cdots \ge S(f_{\sigma(P)}) \ge  \cdots \ge S(f_{\sigma(K)})\,.$$

Your weighted sum is therefore:

$$\Phi_P = \sum_{p=1}^P (P-p+1)S(f_{\sigma(p)}) \,.$$

I don't have a standard and clean writing of the first top-$P$ numbers of an integer set, hence the bijection.

An example is given below with Matlab code.

[image: Spectrum and selected peaks]

```
nFrequency = 100;
nPeak = 10;
dataSpectrum = rand(nFrequency,1);

weightPeak = linspace(nPeak,1,nPeak);
[amplitudePeak,indexPeak] = maxk(dataSpectrum,nPeak);

figure(1);clf;hold on
plot(dataSpectrum)
plot(indexPeak,dataSpectrum(indexPeak),'o')

weightedPeakSum = weightPeak*amplitudePeak;
```